# How to use \K for regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

`\K` means reset the begining of match, which can be very useful when complex lookbehind is not supported (i.e., it doesn't allow + and * for lookbehind). It addresses my needs very well, however, when I tried to use it in python, it reports `bad escape \K`. The following is my python code:

```py
re.sub(r'\[\n[ ]+\d+, ?\n[ ]+\K\d+(?=, ?\n[ ]+(?:true|false)\n[ ]+\])', '__table1.column__', content)
```

Comment: You could use a capturing group `(\[\n[ ]+\d+, ?\n[ ]+)\d+(, ?\n[ ]+(?:true|false)\n[ ]+\])` and use `\1__table1.column__\2` in the replacement https://regex101.com/r/s0yvJr/1

Comment: @TheFourthBird You should omit `\2`, the meaning of `\K` is simply "match from here on".

Comment: @tripleee I think the OP wants to replace the digits between the 2 patterns with `__table1.column__`. When using `\K` it will look like https://regex101.com/r/vX8bIX/1 If I omit the `\2` it will not match the logic in the lookahead from the original pattern.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I missed how you switched from a lookahead to a regular match.

Comment: You should probably post this as an answer; yours is better than both the currently proposed answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use 2 capturing groups instead:

```
(\[\n[ ]+\d+, ?\n[ ]+)\d+(, ?\n[ ]+(?:true|false)\n[ ]+\])
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/oSJAgI) | [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/51fgx2/1)

In the replacement use:

```
\1__table1.column__\2
```

For example

```
re.sub(
    r'(\[\n[ ]+\d+, ?\n[ ]+)\d+(, ?\n[ ]+(?:true|false)\n[ ]+\])',
    r'\1__table1.column__\2',
    content
)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly for me. So I guess there is no direct support for \K for regex in python?

Comment: Not directly, but you could use the regex module answered by DeepSpace.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module that supports it.

Comment: so, \K can be used if I use this regex library

Answer (score 0):

You could use the positive look behind `(?<=...)`

So, for example, you want to read everything after a http div:

```
<label>Lorem Ipsum</label>
```

This regex  `(?<=<label>).*` will return:

```
Lorem Ipsum</label>
```

Meanwhile, if you want to remove the last div part `</label>`, you can use the positive look ahead: `(?=...)`, like so:

`(?<=<label>).*(?=</label>)`

This will return the label div content:

```
Lorem Ipsum
```